# Why is my django-filter input box not appearing?

Tags: python, django, django-filter

Why is my django-filter input box not appearing? I am trying to replace a search bar with this filtering system so when they search for a particular username at the header, they will be directed to an account/filter_results.html page to show the filtered results. However, only the submit button appears but not the input box. Kindly advise

filters.py

```
import django_filters

from account.models import Account


class UserNameFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    username = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['username']
```

views.py

```
def account_search_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = {}
    account = Account.objects.all()
    context['account'] = account 
    username = UserNameFilter(request.GET, queryset=Account.objects.all())
    context['username'] = username
    return render(request, "account/filter_results.html", context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('search/', account_search_view, name="search"),
]
```

header.html page

```
<form method="get">
{{ username.form }}
<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

filter_results.html page

```
    {% for obj in username.qs %}
        {{ obj.email }} - ${{ obj.price }}<br />
    {% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
 email                  = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
 username               = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got your error here it is

```
    return render(request, "account/filter_results.html", context)
```

you are passing your context to `filter_results.html` and you are trying to access in `header.html`
if you want to access your form in `header.html` page than pass context there also like this

```
return render(request, "account/header.html", context)
```

Comment: hello :) nope, for django filters i think is username.form and not form.username

Comment: for more information check this post https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/28/how-to-filter-querysets-dynamically.html

Comment: @kknam was it usefull to you.

Comment: sorry nope, it did not work, and so I switched to using a search bar instead